# How to update a specific value in object of MongoDb via Post?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, post

I have a schema with sub objects, i want to be able to update a specific key inside of it. If i update only a specific key - like in the Post example - it's empty all the other keys..

for example :

```
{ 
  "_id": "32323323",
  "names":{
            "firstname":"John",
            "lastname":"foo",

            "workers":{
                "position":"manager",
                 "address":"1 st"
            }
          }
}
```

I want to update Only "position" key via Post request , for example :

```
   $.post({
            url: 'workers/information/',
            data: {
                user_id: user_id,
                names: {
                    workers: {
                        position: some data,
                    }
                }
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert('Your information updated successfully')

            }

    });
```

Here is the update method in NodeJs server :

```
 UserDataController.updateWorkersInformation = function (userID, workersInformation, cb) {

   if (userID) {
      user.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userID}, workersInformation, function (err, result) {
             if (err) return cb(err);
             return cb(null, result);
          });
     }
 };
```

Comment: Try `user.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userID}, {$set:{"names.worker.position": workersInformation.names.workers.position}}, function (err, result) {...`

Comment: Thanks !!! works great !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into mongoose. It provides a more simple interface than the native client does.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose

However, as the comment mentioned, you are missing the $set operator. {$set:workersInformation}

If update is called without the $set operator, the entire document will be replaced with your update object.

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/tutorials/crud/

Comment: That's what i was looking for - Thanks!